# Why is there no UML or other model added to the DOM specifications?

Tags: model, dom

I already went through several versions of the DOM and HTML specifications on the W3C's websites but I have never seen a complete overview model or meta model regarding the DOM or the HTML.

Additionally I also failed to find such a model on other websites.

Is there a good reason for that, for example does the DOM not fulfill the criteria of being a valid model (which I doubt but who knows)?

Comment: What do you want in UML? The DOM is a specification for handling markup text, not a set of classes.

Comment: So there are no classes involved and no objects created in the process of parsing HTML into a DOM tree structure?

Comment: @JulianZucker The DOM is an Document Object Model – it does define a fairly complex class hierarchy. E.g. an Element is-a Node.

Comment: And my question is why there has been no attempt yet to present this hierarchy using a single or multiple model(s).

Comment: Such questions are not well suited for this site - the W3 DOM [mailing list](https://www.w3.org/DOM/MailingList) would be a much better place to ask. You were lucky to find someone among our community who seems to know enough about the W3 to give you a good answer, but normally if you want something to know about an external site, better ask the site owners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3C technical reports such as the DOM specification are authored with the ReSpec tool. Interfaces are described with the language-agnostic WebIDL interface description language. It would in theory be possible to autogenerate UML from the WebIDL source, however the ReSpec tool provides no such support.

For specifications it is very desirable that the document is always consistent. Thus tools that check cross-references and regenerate views from a single source of truth are very desirable. This also means that it is undesirable to generate UML diagrams with external tools, as those diagrams could then fall out of sync with the source.

Note that diagrams also have accessibility issues, e.g. for blind users. So they must not be a source of information but can merely be an illustration of information that is described elsewhere. This also suggests that they are superfluous in the strictest sense.

If you want to see UML diagrams in W3C reports, your best strategy would be to develop a ReSpec plugin and get involved with W3C working groups that would benefit from UML diagrams in their reports.